# Can you run multiple app on 1 LAMP?

Tags: web-applications, lamp

I'm newer at this and I was wondering if one LAMP instance or physical machine  (either or) can run multiple app such as NextCloud and Nagios for say.

Or if I have to deploy multiple LAMPs which at that point I'll be looking to use Docker containers.

Thanks.

Comment: Go to serverfault.com website - https://serverfault.com/questions/613763/how-to-run-multiple-php-apps-on-a-single-lamp-instance

Comment: please check my answer below

Comment: is it acceptable answer for your question?

Comment: @VedPrakash  I didn't think SF was the place for this question, I am on SF as well

Comment: @VedPrakash I have seen and read your answer. It makes sense, I will give it a try and see. I'll let you know

Comment: okay I am  waiting for your response

Comment: I think so that's why I am suggesting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply Add another virtual host entry if in case you want to assign different domain name later :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/folder2
    <Directory /var/www/folder2>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [QSA,L]
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined 
</VirtualHost>
```

OR

if you just want access it just like example.com/folder than just add a folder inside the directory /var/www/folder1/ named folder2.